# SQL join two different tables on timestamp

Tags: sql, join, timestamp, impala

Excuse the poor formatting, I will try to keep this clear:

Table A

```
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|
 |      col1           |     col2         |   datetime   |
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

Table B

```
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|
 |      col3           |     col4         |   datetime   |
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

The output I'm looking for is something like this

```
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|-----------|---------------|
 |      col1           |     col2         |   col3       |   col4    |   datetime    |             
 |---------------------|------------------|--------------|-----------|---------------|
```

Basically, the datetime column should be the key and should contain all values from both tables ( no duplicates ) , and the respective values found in the tables should appear for each timestamp ( or NULL when there is none )

I have tried with FULL OUTER JOIN but it seems to be skipping some datetimes:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col3, T2.col4, T1.datetime
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN  T2 on T1.datetime=T2.datetime;
```

Also I tried a left join on a right join subquery, but still no luck.

I feel this should have an easy solution. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, it is not "skipping" datetime values.  Instead, they appear as `NULL`.  You can fix this with `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col3, T2.col4,
       COALESCE(T1.datetime, T2.datetime) as datetime
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     T2 
     ON T1.datetime = T2.datetime;
```

Most databases that support `FULL JOIN` also support the standard `USING` clause, so you can also express this as:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T2.col3, T2.col4,
       datetime
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     T2 
     USING (datetime);
```

Comment: ...so the values from the second table appeared as NULL if they weren't in the first one, but the col values were nevertheless copied. I couldn't tell because i was ordering by datetime so all the NULLs were at the end. Your first solution worked perfectly @Gordon . Thanks!

Comment: @habarnam . . . This is not uncommon when using `full join`.  It is really much trickier than the other `join` types.